# New tag request for Brightburn (2019 movie)

Tags: support, tags

[Brightburn](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7752126/), a 2019 movie is classified as **Drama, Horror, Mystery** on IMDb.

However, the summary of the movie is as follows:

> What if a child from another world crash-landed on Earth, but instead of becoming a hero to mankind, he proved to be something far more sinister?

The movie basically revolves around a spaceship crash-lands in Brightburn, Kansas on a farm and inside the ship is an infant child. The child is adopted by a couple. He finds out that he sin't of this Earth and has superpowers.

To quote **The New York Times**, the story basically asks the question:

> *What if Clark Kent had been a power-hungry sociopath whose motto was* “**take the world**”?

This story is somewhat of a Horror- Science fiction mix. Therefore, I think we would need a tag `Brightburn` or `Brightburn-2019` for the questions related to this movie.

Comment: Tags are only created when they are on a question. You have enough rep to do this yourself as well when asking a question about it should you wish so.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Well I do have some questions. nevertheless, I always thought tag creation needed 20k rep..

Comment: [300](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) for tag creation but for [creating tag wikis is different](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) but you can still suggest an edit to them even now, that privilege just means you don’t need to suggest the edit anymore.

Comment: Question #1. Why did Brightburn concentrate on the least interesting part of Superman's life?

Comment: @Valorum - Because they wanted to focus on horror. When you have an evil adult Superman, then he is just a supervillain, and that story has been done so many times besides. But by scaling it down and focusing on him terrorizing a small town, you have a typical horror movie setting.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are only created when they first are used on a question. [Searching for `brightburn`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=brightburn) yielded 0 results, so we don't have any questions to tag with it and hence don't have that tag.

According to [this stack's privileges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you only need 300 points of reputation to create a new tag. You have quite a bit more than that. You already exceed the 5000 rep points threshold to approving tag wiki edits and are on your way to becoming a trusted user.

So when you ask your questions, just add [brightburn](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brightburn) and that's all — except please, don't forget to fill in the usage guidance and tag wiki.